# SSH AWS ec2 pem key invalid format

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, amazon-web-services, openssh

I'm trying to ssh from arch Linux to Ubuntu AWS instance using OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g. But i get invalid format from the pem key.
But when i use the same key in my Ubuntu machine using  openssh 7.2p2  open ssl 1.0.2g it works fine.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcsiG.png)

I installed putty in arch Linux machine and it works fine also. Is it a bug in the latest release or I'm i missing some thing...

Comment: Did you use PuTTYGen?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: yes, i converted the file when i used with putty, and it works. Also pem file works in ubuntu. Only this issue comes in my arch machine which has the openssh 8.3